# Getting images in second peer using WebRTC (without a server)

Tags: javascript, webrtc, broadcast, videochat

I'm creating one direction call, but I can't receive the images in the second peer.

## My application has the following code:

### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WebRTC</title>
    <style>
        body,
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: #20262E;
        }

        video {
            width: 100%
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="initialize">initialize</button>
    <video autoplay></video>
    <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="carai.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Javascript

```js
const startButton = document.querySelector('button#initialize')
const video = document.querySelector('video')
const confPeer = {}
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('loc')
const peer = new RTCPeerConnection(confPeer)

//
// SIMULATE WEBSOCKET
//

channel.addEventListener('message', message => {
    let {
        action,
        value
    } = message.data

    switch (action) {
        case 'offer':
            startButton.remove()
            answer(value)
            break

        case 'answer':
            done(value)
            break

        default:
            console.error('wtf')
    }
})

// 
// START CALL
// 

const start = async () => {
    console.log('----- start')

    const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        // audio: true,
        video: true
    })

    video.srcObject = localStream

    localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => peer.addTrack(track, localStream));

    let offer = await peer.createOffer()

    peer.setLocalDescription(offer)

    channel.postMessage({
        action: 'offer',
        value: JSON.stringify(offer)
    })
}

//
// ANSWER CALL
//

const done = receivedAnswer => {
    console.log('----- done')
    peer.setRemoteDescription(JSON.parse(receivedAnswer))
}

//
// ESTABLISH CALL
// 

const answer = async receivedOffer => {
    console.log('----- answer')

    peer.ontrack = e => {
        console.log('----- ontrack', e)
        video.srcObject = e.streams[0];
    }

    receivedOffer = JSON.parse(receivedOffer)

    let desc = new RTCSessionDescription(receivedOffer)

    peer.setRemoteDescription(desc)

    let answer = await peer.createAnswer()

    await peer.setLocalDescription(answer)

    channel.postMessage({
        action: 'answer',
        value: JSON.stringify(answer)
    })
}

//
// INITIALIZE
//

startButton.addEventListener('click', start)
```

The caller() saves the information in a localStorage, which called() reads and uses to accept the call, which receives getRemoteStreams, but I can´t play it in the video element.

can anyone help-me with this?

This is my first time using WebRTC, I know I'm missing something.

---

It works in Chrome when I click the start button a second time, but it displays the following depreciation message in the terminal:

[image: depreciation message]

Comment: Rather than using LocalStorage, why not `postMessage`?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I changed the localStorage to the Broadcast Channel, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

*localStorage* as a signaling-channel is a neat trick to demo calls between two tabs.

But you've only completed half the circle of the offer/answer exchange. You need to get the answer back to the caller. E.g.

```
localStorage.setItem('b', JSON.stringify(answer))
```

...and then add code that receives it and calls `setRemoteDescription(answer)` on the 1st peer.

You also need to exchange of ICE candidates, which complicates things.

FWIW I've written [localSocket](https://jan-ivar.github.io/localSocket/localSocket.js) helper class that helps with this. Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/2yLakm60/) (open in 2 tabs).

Lastly, `getRemoteStreams()` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/getRemoteStreams), and isn't needed here since you use `ontrack`.

Comment: Ok, I added ```localStorage.setItem('b', JSON.stringify(answer))``` in called(), and I writed a a function ```const finish = () => peer.setRemoteDescription(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('b')))
``` (I'm calling it after open second tab (peer)).

but I don't no how 'exchange of ICE candidates'...

I Updated the answer with my new code

Comment: can you make a fork of  http://jsfiddle.net/vanuatu/yg6uoq41/17 and show me what I'm missing??

Comment: @DanieldeAndradeVarela Sorry I don't have time. Did you check out the [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/2yLakm60/) I linked to? It's all there. ICE: `pc.onicecandidate = ({candidate}) => sc.send({candidate});` and `if (candidate) await pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);`

Comment: I read it again and I realize what I'm doing wrong, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the great @jib I understood what I was doing wrong. here is the correct code for those are passing to the same situation.

MUITO OBRIGADO @jig

```js
const startButton = document.querySelector('button#initialize')
const video = document.querySelector('video')
const confPeer = {}
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('loc')
const peer = new RTCPeerConnection(confPeer)

//
// SIMULATE WEBSOCKET
//

channel.addEventListener('message', message => {
    let {
        action,
        value
    } = message.data

    switch (action) {
        case 'offer':
            startButton.remove()
            answer(value)
            break

        case 'icecandidate':
            icecandidate(value)
            break

        case 'answer':
            done(value)
            break

        default:
            console.error('wtf')
    }
})

// 
// PEER A: START CALL
// 

const start = async () => {
    console.log('----- start')

    const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        // audio: true,
        video: true
    })

    peer.onicecandidate = ev => {
        console.log('candidate', ev.candidate)
        channel.postMessage({
            action: 'icecandidate',
            value: JSON.stringify(ev.candidate)
        })
    }

    video.srcObject = localStream

    localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => peer.addTrack(track, localStream));

    let offer = await peer.createOffer()

    peer.setLocalDescription(offer)

    channel.postMessage({
        action: 'offer',
        value: JSON.stringify(offer)
    })
}

//
// PEER A: ANSWER CALL
//

const done = receivedAnswer => {
    console.log('----- done')
    peer.setRemoteDescription(JSON.parse(receivedAnswer))
}

//
// PEER B: ICE CANDIDATE
//

const icecandidate = receivedIcecandidate => {
    let candidate = JSON.parse(receivedIcecandidate)
    console.log('received icecandidate', candidate)
    peer.addIceCandidate(candidate)
}

//
// PEER B: ESTABLISH CALL
// 

const answer = async receivedOffer => {
    console.log('----- answer')

    peer.ontrack = e => {
        console.log('----- ontrack', e)
        video.srcObject = e.streams[0];
    }

    receivedOffer = JSON.parse(receivedOffer)

    let desc = new RTCSessionDescription(receivedOffer)

    peer.setRemoteDescription(desc)

    let answer = await peer.createAnswer()

    await peer.setLocalDescription(answer)

    channel.postMessage({
        action: 'answer',
        value: JSON.stringify(answer)
    })
}

//
// INITIALIZE
//

startButton.addEventListener('click', start)
```